# Обход двоичного дерева "в ширину" (breadth-first). Каким образом можно переписать данный алгоритм чтобы он работал быстрее?

Tags: javascript

```
const MAX_NODE_COUNT = 100000;   

function createWideTree() {
    var root = { n: 1, children: [] };
    for(var i=2; i<=MAX_NODE_COUNT; i++) {
        root.children.push({ n: i });
    }
    return root;
}
var root = createDeepTree();    

function* breadthTraversalTree(root) {
    const rootChildren = root.children;
    yield root;

    while(rootChildren.length) {
        let firstChild =  rootChildren.shift();
        yield firstChild;

        if(firstChild.children) {
            rootChildren.push(...firstChild.children);
        }
    }
}

    source tree (root = 1):
 *
 *            1
 *          / | \
 *         2  3  4
 *        / \     \            =>    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
 *       5   6     7
 *           |
 *           8
```

Comment: что это за алгоритм? что он делает? для каких входных данных?

Comment: Принимает корень двоичного дерева и возвращает sequence of all tree nodes in breadth-first order.

Comment: _sequence of all tree nodes in breadth-first order_ - что это значит? :-)

Comment: вообще, обрати внимание, что у тебя портится входной объект. А хотя вообще непонятно, что ты делаешь с входным объектом. Если тебе надо только вывести последовательность, зачем менять сам объект?

Comment: Добавь пример входных данных, и пример соответствующего вывода: для правки вопроса используй кнопку [edit] под вопросом

Comment: И теперь пример самого js объекта, не просто нарисовать, а именно структура какая у него

Comment: Сколько уровней может быть в дереве? функция _createWideTree_ создает всего один уровень, и для обхода созданного объекта нужен всего один цикл по массиву children

Comment: Уровней может быть много.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал через двойной связанный список, можно было через одинарный лист, но просто у меня были заранее заиплеменченные методы.

```
class Node {
  constructor(data = null, prev = null, next = null) {
    this.data = data;
    this.prev = prev;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.length = 0;
    this._head = null;
    this._tail = null;
  }

  append(data) {
    var node = new Node(data);

    if (this.length === 0) {
      this._head = node;
      this._tail = node;
    } else {
      this._tail.next = node;
      node.prev = this._tail;
      this._tail = node;
    }

    this.length++;
    return this;
  }

  nodeAt(index) {
    var currentNode = this._head;
    var length = this.length;
    var count = 0;
    var message = {
      failure: 'Failure: non-existent node in this list.'
    };

    if (length === 0 || index < 0 || index > length) {
      throw new Error(message.failure);
    }

    while (count < index) {
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
      count++;
    }
    return currentNode;
  }

  deleteAt(index) {
    if (this.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.length) {
      var message = {
        failure: 'Failure: non-existent node in this list.'
      };
      throw new Error(message.failure);
    }
    if (this.length === 1) {
      this._head.data = null;
      this._tail.data = null;
    } else if (index === 0) {
      this.nodeAt(1).prev = null;
      this._head = this.nodeAt(1);
    } else if (index === this.length - 1) {
      this.nodeAt(index - 1).next = null;
      this._tail = this.nodeAt(index - 1);
    } else {
      this.nodeAt(index - 1).next = this.nodeAt(index + 1);
      this.nodeAt(index + 1).prev = this.nodeAt(index - 1);
    }
    this.length--;
    return this;
  }
}

function* breadthTraversalTree(root) {
  let queue = new LinkedList();
  queue.append(root);

  while (queue.length) {
    let n = new Node();
    n.data = queue._head.data;
    queue.deleteAt(0);

    if (n.data.children) {
      n.data.children.forEach(x => queue.append(x));
    }
    yield n.data;
  }
}
```